# How to Add MX Player as the default player in an android application?

Tags: java, android, vitamio

I want a way to set up a MX Player to play videos in my application.

Answer (score 0):

This will launch any installed version of MX Player(Not tested).You need to add data to the intent to play videos. Good luck with your app.

```
Intent intent;
PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
try {
    intent= packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro");
    if (null != intent)this.startActivity(intent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //MX Player pro isn't installed
    try{
        intent= packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
        if (null != intent)this.startActivity(intent);
       }
       catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       //No version of MX Player is installed.You should let the user know
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for answering
But when you press the button, every program opens and does not play the video

Comment: What you mean by"every program opening"?

Comment: I mean it opens the Mx program and shows inside it all the videos in the device